# Weird issue when using \limits

Tags: bugs

I am writing a summary of my lecture notes when the command `\limits` acted very strangely: it wrote the bounds below and above but also acted like the `\newpage` command.

Those are the document characteristics, I use an A4 paper in landscape with 3 columns.
Additionally I wrote a special environment for `leftbar`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5cm,landscape]{geometry}

\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts, verbatim, enumerate}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{harvard}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{showidx}


\usepackage[light,english,all]{draftcopy}

\renewenvironment{leftbar}{%
    \OuterFrameSep=0ex plus .8ex
    \def\FrameCommand{{\vrule width 1pt}\hspace{3pt}}%
    \MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}
    \noindent\ignorespaces
    }{%
    \endMakeFramed
    \csname@endparenv\endcsname
}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
```

I enclose herewith the screenshots showing the problem.
Here the code before:
[image]

And after (the issue is at the cursor):
[image]

And that is what happened to the pdf.
Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Does anyone know what this is due to?

Many thanks in advice for your answers!

Comment: Please no screenshot. Post *code* which we can copy/paste, preferrably a *complete*, *minimal* code from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`.

Comment: You shouldn't be using limits here in the first place. There is a reason why latex does this. On the other hand, you really need to learn about displayed math

Comment: you seem to have `\limits` after ever `\sum` and `\int`  you may (very) occasionaly need to use `\limits `to force a non standard layout but you should never need to use it regularly.